# Show that there exists a reference frame where the two events happen at the same time

Tags: special-relativity

### question

I am trying to show that if the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* is negative
$$c^2 \Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2<0$$
then there exists a reference frame $S^{'}$ where $\Delta t^{'}=0$.

### context

consider a pair of reference frames $S$ and $S^{'}$.

[image]

$S^{'}$ is sliding away from $S$ at constant velocity $v$ along a common $x$, $x^{'}$ axis.

Consider two events $E1$ and $E2$.

From the perspective of an observer in $S$, $E1$ happens at $(x_{1},t_{1})$ and $E2$ happens at $(x_{2},t_{2})$.

From the perspective of an observer in $S^{'}$, $E1$ happens at $(x^{'}_{1},t^{'}_{1})$ and $E2$ happens at $(x^{'}_{2},t^{'}_{2})$.

We can relate the events in the two reference frames using the Lorentz transformations.

$$x^{'}=\gamma(x- v t)$$
$$t^{'}=\gamma(t- \frac{v}{c^2} t)$$

where as usual:
$\gamma = (1- \frac{v^2}{c^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

The differences between the events can be denoted.

$$\Delta x = x_2 -x_1$$
$$\Delta t = t_2 -t_1$$
$$\Delta x^{'} = x^{'}_2 -x^{'}_1$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = t^{'}_2 -t^{'}_1$$

Using the Lorentz transformations we are able to express the space and time separations between the events in terms of the coordinates in the first reference frame and $v$ the speed of $S^{'}$ relative to $S$.
$$\Delta x^{'} = \gamma (\Delta x - v \Delta t)$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \frac{v}{c^2}\Delta x)$$

## Attempt 1.

So my task is prove that a reference frame exists where $\Delta t^{'}=0$.

I guess I can do this by defining such a reference frame.
How do I define a reference frame?

I guess I can define a reference frame $S^{'}$ by choosing its velocity $v$.
(This is the velocity relative to the other reference frame).

I see that I could choose $v=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}c^2$.
If I plug this $v$ into $\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \frac{v}{c^2}\Delta x)$. Then I get:
$$\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \frac{v}{c^2}\Delta x)$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \frac{\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}c^2}{c^2}\Delta x)$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = \gamma (\Delta t - \Delta t)$$
$$\Delta t^{'} = 0$$

But this is nothing to do with the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* being negative??

Help appreciated!

> How do I show that the negative-ness of the *Lorentz Invariant Interval* implies that there exists a reference frame $S^{'}$ with $\Delta t^{'}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have $|v| < c$.

When $v = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} c^2$, we require $c |\Delta t| < |\Delta x|$, which is equivalent to the Lorentz Invariant Interval being negative.